# ¿Como puedo hacer funcionar mi servidor local con una ruta en especifico con PHP?

Tags: linux, apache

Tengo un inconveniente con mi servidor local.

Estoy utilizando Apache y a su vez, estoy virtualizando para así obtener por ejemplo: `milocal.com`

El problema es que yo necesito tenerlo de ésta manera: `milocal.com/proyecto`
y después por medio de código le agrego otra ruta al realizar una acción en especifico; lo que pasa es que si hago las pruebas con `milocal.com` si me funciona bien, pero cuando lo hago con `milocal/proyecto` ya no funciona incluso cuando reviso los errores de consola en la respuesta del servidor me arroja el html de la página.

**Nota:** La cuestión es que necesito que al momento de entrar a `milocal.com/proyecto` lo tome como si fuera solamente `milocal.com` ya que es un modulo adicional.

Comment: No me queda claro por qué es que no creas la carpeta `proyecto` dentro de tu DocumentRoot y solucionas el problema

Comment: El problema es que necesito que **milocal.com/proyecto** lo tomara como si fuera solo **milocal.com**

Answer (score 1):

¿Estás usando Virtual Host de Apache?. Asegúrate que tienes un directorio donde estará tu sitio (usualmente y por convención se coloca en `/var/www/tusitioweb`). Te sugiero uses siempre el nombre del dominio para facilidad de mantenimiento (en este ejemplo sería `/var/www/milocal.com`). Debes darle permisos al servidor web (usualmente el usuario es www-data que debe tener permisos de lectura para todos y lectura y escritura para www-data. Esto permitirá a tus scripts en PHP manipular la información en esos directorios).

También asegúrate que tienes un archivo de hosting virtual en `/etc/apache2/sites-available/milocal.com` (o cualquiera que sea tu dominio).
Para este ejemplo el archivo quedaría más o menos así:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName milocal.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/milocal.com/proyecto
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/milocal.com/proyecto>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Finalmente no olvides activar esta configuración con:

```
a2ensite milocal.com
```

para luego reiniciar el servidor apache con:

```
service apache2 restart
```

P.D: No olvides direccionar tu servidor DNS a la dirección IP de tu máquina.

Comment: El problema es que necesito que **milocal.com/proyecto** lo tome como si fuera solo **milocal.com**

Comment: Si entendí  bien lo que deseas es que cuando alguien escriba http://milocal.com en un navegador el servidor apache en tu máquina muestre la página que está almacenada en el subdirectorio milocal.com/proyecto. Si esto es así la configuración de arriba hace exactamente eso. El secreto está en lo que pongas en las líneas ServerName y DocumentRoot. Si esto no es lo que deseas te suplico elabores aún más tu pregunta y trataré de hacer lo mejor para responderte.

Comment: Tengo un virtualhost llamado `milocal.com`, pero estoy haciendo la otra parte de mi página la cual sería: `milocal.com/proyecto` y necesito que `milocal.com/proyecto` sea tratado como la raiz del **HTTP_HOST** y no como la **URI**

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es arrancar tu aplicación puedes hacerlo de una forma fácil ejecutando lo siguiente en la raíz de tu proyecto

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Luego abres esa dirección en tu navegador y ya podrás ver lo que estas desarrollando.

[Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php) puedes encontrar mas información acerca de esto.